# Rails parameters are different when posting the same payload via Curl or Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, curl

When posting the same basic JSON from Android or via curling, the result is different.

I'm trying to understand why? I'm assuming there is something about Rails that I don't understand.

**Command Line HTTP POST**

> curl 'http://localhost:3000/mobile/register' -X POST -H 'Content-Type:
>   application/json' -d '{"user": {"email": "awesome@example.com",
>   "password":"helloworld", "password_confirmation":"helloworld"}}'

Server logs

> Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"awesome@example.com",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
>   "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"awesome@example.com",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}

**Android HTTP POST**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject();

userObject.put("email", mUserEmail);
userObject.put("password", mUserPassword);
userObject.put("password_confirmation", mUserPasswordConfirmation);

String userString = userObject.toString();

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("user", userString)
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(REGISTER_API_ENDPOINT_URL)
        .method("POST", RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]))
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);
call.enqueue(new Callback()...
```

Server logs

> Parameters:
>   {"user"=>"{\"email\":\"awesome@example.com\",\"password\":\"helloworld\",\"password_confirmation\":\"helloworld\"}"}

**Rails Routes:**

```
devise_scope :user do 
    namespace :mobile do
      post '/register', to: 'registrations#create', as: :register
    end
end
```

**Differences:**

- curling hides the password but Android does not
- curling adds an additional nested JSON with all the data repeated

I'm not sure what causes these differences?

### UPDATE

I checked `request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"]` in the controller action and I am seeing differences in `Content-Type`.

Curl -> `application/json`

Android -> `multipart/form-data; boundary=...`

Could this cause the issue?

Is it easy to change from the Android side? I added `.header("Content-Type", "application/json")` to the request but it makes no difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Android HTTP POST lacks the `Content-Type: application/json` header because it sends multipart form data . So the rails app logs it as plain string data instead of parsing it, registering user and filtering password.

Also, in case of `curl` command, the parsed JSON user object is used to register a user. The repeated log entry is perhaps done during this user registration.

To make both requests equivalent,  try using the `POST TO A SERVER` example given at http://square.github.io/okhttp/.